# Не работает documentElement.clientWidth в функции всплывающего окна

Tags: javascript, jquery

Решил изменить размеры всплывающего окна в функции, порылся в интернете и решил, что можно сделать это при помощи конструкции

```
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 482) {...} else {...}
```

но окно в первом условии (< 482) осталось без изменений,тоесть растянуто на всю ширину экрана, а вторая часть условия отработала прекрасно и всплывающее окно получилось нужного размера, я также попробовал сделать это при помощи

```
(window.innerWidth < 482) и (document.body.clientWidth < 482) и ($(window).width() < 482)
```

еще пробовал поменять условия if и else местами, безрезультатно.
Ошибок в консоли не обнаружено, вот сама функция:

```
function DLEalert(a, c) {
    $("#dlepopup").remove();
    $("body").append("<div id='dlepopup' class='dle-alert' title='" + c + "' style='display:none'>" + a + "</div>");

     if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 482) { 
     $("#dlepopup").dialog({
        autoOpen: !0,
        width: 280,
        resizable: !1,
        dialogClass: "modalfixed dle-popup-alert",
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $("#dlepopup").remove()
            }
        }
    });}
    else {
         $("#dlepopup").dialog({
        autoOpen: !0,
        width: 450,
        resizable: !1,
        dialogClass: "modalfixed dle-popup-alert",
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $("#dlepopup").remove()
            }
        }
    });
    }

    $(".modalfixed.ui-dialog").css({
        position: "fixed"
    });
    $("#dlepopup").dialog("option", "position", ["0", "0"])

}
```

Подскажите, что неправильно делаю и как исправить?

- Небольшое дополнение: если оставить только одно работающее условие (без if else) и поменять ширину на 100px то на экранах больше 600px popup будет 100px а если меньше 600px то окно растягивается по всей ширине экрана

Comment: Если ваш проект адаптивный, то можно брать ширину div-a обертки. Например ваш проект обернут в div c id="container", то 
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
if (containerWidth  < 482) {
...
}  else  {
...
}

Comment: Попробовал, не получилось, не могу понять в чем дело, но что-то перебивает эти параметры, и окно растягивается на всю ширину экрана в девайсах с экраном меньше 600px

Comment: Тогда тут много вариантов, может скрипт принудительно растягивает, может стили принудительно растягивают, может в логику диалога это заложено. В общем нужно разбираться. Дайте ссылку на проект, если он онлайн.

Comment: Kydrid, вы  правы, стили принудительно растягивали width 100% !important а я сразу не заметил, сейчас все работает как надо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел, что не давало возможности задать нужный размер в JS: в стилях для ui-dialog в @media{max-width:590px}было прописано width:100% !important и это имело больший приоритет чем значение в js, так что теперь все работает

Answer (score 0):

Эта конструкция:

```
document.documentElement.clientWidth
```

работает только в MS Internet Explorer

А вот window.innerWidth должна работать

Comment: Только что еще раз перепроверил с window.innerWidth, не меняеться размер, и заметил еще одну особенность, если проверять с размером экрана больше 600px то окно как и положено 450px в ширину, а если размер к примеру 533 и меньше (тестировал на реальном устройстве) то уже при 533 popup тянется на всю ширину экрана (хотя должен быть 450), может в этом причина? но немогу понять как это работает...

Comment: Да, я думаю, дело в масштабировании экрана. Я бы добавил в расчёт ширину экрана (screen.width)